# How to make an infinite flow sequence of a shape in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

[image]I am trying to create an infinite flow of the shape:

```
def draw_tree(x):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BROWN, [60+x,400,30,45])
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, GREEN, [[150+x, 400],[75+x, 250],[0+x, 400]])
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, GREEN, [[140+x, 350],[75+x, 230],[10+x, 350]])
```

creating the movement as:

```
for i in range(10):
    draw_tree(x+150*i)

x += 1
```

in the main code. How to make this sequence infinite?

Comment: Doing _what_ infinite, exactly?

Comment: A linear infinite chain of shapes

Comment: Would that mean that you `for` loop should run forever?

Comment: want to make the shape reappear from the front as it disappears from the rear

Comment: But currently it is not disappearing, you just add new? Also, are you working with a set screen resolution? If so, what is this?

Comment: Just start to blit at -150, make the row of trees wider than the screen width and then reset x to 0 if it's `>= 150`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that demonstrates what I described in the comment. The for loop starts to draw the 6 trees at i = -150 to which you add the current x offset. If x is `>= 150` simply reset it to 0.

```
import sys
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
BROWN = pg.Color('brown')
GREEN = pg.Color('green4')


def draw_tree(x):
    pg.draw.rect(screen, BROWN, [60+x, 400, 30, 45])
    pg.draw.polygon(screen, GREEN, [[150+x, 400], [75+x, 250], [0+x, 400]])
    pg.draw.polygon(screen, GREEN, [[140+x, 350], [75+x, 230], [10+x, 350]])


def main():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    x = 0
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True

        x += 4
        if x >= 150:
            x = 0

        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        for i in range(-150, 4*150+1, 150):
            draw_tree(i+x)
        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```